# QMake build static library using dlls

Tags: qt5, qmake

I have a Qt project which is a library.

Currently it works great but it is a dll and I want it to be a static library.

To do so I added "CONFIG += static" in my .pro file (I also tried "CONFIG += staticlib"). After doing so my library compiles well but it needs to be statically linked to libraries which were DLLs before.

Is there a way to compile a static library using dlls with QMake ? ?

Comment: Static library must be linked statically. That's hardly a surprise. Your question is unclear. Maybe you miss something about libraries in general?

Comment: I lnow that static libs must be linked staticallyto my exe, but I thought a static lib could call a dll without having to do LoadLibrary / getProcAddress / FreeLibray or all the things related,

Comment: "Must be linked" = "all external calls must be resolved later" (i.e. upon linking step).